# Can you run 32-bit IceCat or IceWeasel on Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, noobs, web-browsers

I just got my RPi3 loaded, Raspbian (NOOBS) and tried node-red, but found a problem typing in function. I found out it was the browser's fault. Now I would like to install Firefox (AKA IceCat or IceWeasel). The IceCat is 32-bit. What do you recommend?

Comment: Programs compiled for x86 are not going to work with ARM, a browser I can recommend is Chromium, which is based off Chrome. How do you know the browser is at fault, (I am assuming Epiphany)?

Answer (score 2):

Iceweasel is available and can be installed with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install iceweasel
```